# Convert Google Video URL

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

When i download a video from YouTube(Google docs or Google plus) with a download manager this what i get

> referer: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71zlOWbEoe8
>
> address:
>   http://r4---sn-5hnezn76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=o-AAyCp6dqoOj_sUwGtSwE9J27TU7-iKHf4d209xDnuCee&signature=2EB6338E125E84AAA3736DBCEF6AC35451A2104A.1C29A8A9B830CDC9E4493D93A25BA62FF3672E4A&key=cms1&ipbits=0&fexp=3300091%2C3300111%2C3300130%2C3300137%2C3300164%2C3310366%2C3310648%2C3310698%2C3312169%2C907050%2C908562%2C913434%2C923341%2C924203%2C930008%2C932617%2C935501%2C939936%2C939937&ratebypass=yes&ip=41.230.222.50&upn=DO_DxWpYrpg&expire=1402102715&sparams=expire,gcr,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn&itag=18&source=youtube&gcr=tn&redirect_counter=1&req_id=8a4c0009cb74c822&cms_redirect=yes&ms=nxu&mt=1402081178&mv=m&mws=yes

And I want to know if i have the `address` is there a way to get the `referer`
I mean if i have this : `http ://r4---sn-5hnezn76.googlevideo. com/videoplayback?id......`
how to get http `://www.youtube.com/watch?v=.........` ?